# Paypal Sandbox - can an account have multiple balances in different currencies?

Tags: node.js, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to implement paypal's payouts node sdk to handle payouts to customers. Right now I have set up a couple of accounts in the sandbox (1 merchant - USD, others personal) and payments to accounts that are in USD go fine, but the ones to accounts that are in EUR fail. The only advice I have found by googling is to have balances in USD and EUR in your account but I do not see this option in the sandbox account settings.
Does anyone know a way to deal with this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an account management question not a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sign into the receiving [Developer Portal sandbox account](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts)'s own interface at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com
2. Add a currency balance in the [currency management settings](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/money).